# Cognitive Face API returning No result from Web Application

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using the Microsoft Cognitive Face API for implementing the Face Detection to Authenticate the person and login to the application.

For that, I am creating a PersonGroup and add the Person and then Face of Person. Train Person group and so on.

I want to implement it in the MVC Web Application. I have written the same code in MVC Web Application. But the API is not returning anything and just hanged at the Http request call.

So Do we need to get some different API Key for a Web application or Do we need to make any changes in Web.Config file to make a successful call?

I have tried the same code in the Console Application and WPF Application. There everything works perfectly fine.

```
public class HttpClientHelper
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        private const string subscriptionKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        private const string faceEndpoint = "https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/";

        public HttpClientHelper()
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(faceEndpoint);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(contentString);
        }
    }


public static async Task CreatePersonGroup(UserGroup userGroup)
        {
            bool isGroupExists = false;
            PersonGroup personGroup;

            try
            {
                HttpClientHelper httpClientHelper = new HttpClientHelper();
                var response = httpClientHelper.GetAsync<PersonGroup>(string.Format("persongroups/{0}", userGroup.UserGroupId)).Result;

               isGroupExists = true;
            }
            catch (APIErrorException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Body.Error.Code == "PersonGroupNotFound")
                    isGroupExists = false;
            }

            if (isGroupExists == false)
            {
                await faceClient.PersonGroup.CreateAsync(userGroup.UserGroupId, userGroup.Name);
            }
        }
```

I expect the same code must be working fine in Web Application also. As there is not a big logic in it. Just a simple API call.

Comment: "But the API is not returning anything and just hanged at the Http request call." hanged how? No reply? Timeout at the end? Any exception?

Comment: This isn't a service issue, but rather a threading issue in your UI framework.  Are you able to make the call outside of the UI thread?

Comment: Now everything started working with the same code. The issue I think was from Microsoft side. Which got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string faceEndpoint = 
"https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/";
```

hopefully, it should work

Comment: It is the right thing, when we are using SDK we need to use this URL. But It is not working with API call using HttpClient. Anyway, actually both ways it is working in the Console application. The issue is only with Web application somehow.